# Is socket.io.js supposed to return an empty file?

Tags: node.js

I trying to make a small chat website using node.js and socket.io.
To include the socket.io.js on my client-sided files:

```
    <script src="192.168.0.108:1337/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

But is it normal that it returns an empty file?
http://screencast.com/t/HPAjAqV13q8q

I would also like to add that if on my server-sided file, I do res.write('Hello World'), the 'Hello World' Will appear on the web-page AND in the socket.io.js file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What solved it was opening the port on which socket.io was listening, in my case it was 8080... Now my socket.io.js has javascript code inside of it.

Now I am getting a 404 error on a xhr.send(null) in that socket.io.js file, but that is another story...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<script src='/socket.io/socket.io.js'></script>
```

And you should created a client `io.connect`

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use socket.io's auto-discovery feature and don't specify the server

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect();
</script>
```

Comment: I think that this option would not work as node.js is on my ubuntu server and the client-sided files go to my windows pc, so I need to do: src="http://192.168.0.108:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"

Comment: yeah, but that's the normal case. Your server is running somewhere on Linux and your local machine connects to the server from Windows or Mac. It should nevertheless work! Have you tried it?

Comment: I tried your alternative and it does not work :/. Maybe becuse my node .js files are in /home/me/work-area/node/ and socket.io is in /var/www/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.io